# Can't ping Gateway if Access Point has no internet connection

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi

In my app I programmatically connect to an Access Point that has no access to the internet via `WifiManager` and `WifiConfiguration`. Later on I have to access a device connected to it to read data – but I didn't get that far.

After connecting to the Wifi I'm getting my DHCP setup just fine, but if I try to ping the Gateway address by typing:

```
$ adb shell
OnePlus6:/ $ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1015ms
```

The gateway is unreacheable...

I suspect this has to do with the fact that Android (9?) re-routes all traffic in case of a "dead" Wifi over to mobile data – for example you can still browse the internet just fine.

You can easily replicate the issue like this:

1. Connect to an Access Point w/o internet access
2. Check if your internet still works (e.g. go to google.com)
3. Connect you phone via `adb` and ping the address of your AP

Any ideas on how to force the traffic trough Wifi, even if it's "offline"?

Edit: Output of `ip route show`:

```
OnePlus6:/ $ ip route show
10.16.52.64/29 dev rmnet_data0 proto kernel scope link src 10.16.52.67 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.116
```

Comment: Does your Android device have a data connection too, above the wifi ones?

Comment: Yes, mobile data is always on

Comment: can you please add the result of the following command? ip route show (run it in the adb shell)

Comment: Yes, see my edit please

Comment: it's strange, the routing table seems to be ok. Have you already tried to trace the hops of the ping packet? Try a traceroute to 192.168.1.1, so we can see how the traffic is directed

Comment: Sadly I don't have traceroute installed on the device

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a solution. One has to bind the current process to the correct network, which can be done like this:

```
connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
connectionManager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            connectionManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
        } else {
            ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
        }
    }
});
```